# Caption begins inside table in tufte-book

Tags: tables, captions, tufte-book

If I use the `table*` environment and the table is wide, the caption starts inside the table.  Here is the example

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}

\begin{document}
\begin{table*}[h!]
  \begin{tabular}{l}
    This will be a wide table so that the caption  will start inside the table, unfortunately\\
    This will be a wide table so that the caption  will start inside the table, unfortunately\\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{Notations}
  \label{table:toowide}
\end{table*}
\end{document}
```

I certainly could use a `\bigskip` before the `\caption` as a workaround, but I think moving the caption furher to the right would be preferrable.

[image: table_in_tufte_book]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `tufte-book` captions are placed in a margin. In the case of use of the wide table or figure environment you need define `offset` of caption. Details are described in the package documentation, so here two cases: caption above table and below table:

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
  \begin{tabular}{l}
  \hline
    This will be a wide table so that the caption  will start inside the table, unfortunately\\
    This will be a wide table so that the caption  will start inside the table, unfortunately\\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
  \caption[][-3ex]{Caption is above table}
%  \setfloatalignment{t}
  \label{table:toowide}
\end{table}
\begin{table}[ht]
  \begin{tabular}{l}
  \hline
    This will be a wide table so that the caption  will start inside the table, unfortunately\\
    This will be a wide table so that the caption  will start inside the table, unfortunately\\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
  \caption[][2ex]{Caption is below table}
  \setfloatalignment{b}
  \label{table:toowide}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is already good, thx.  Is it a bad idea to push the caption further to the right?  Is it possible?

Comment: You could change \marginparwidth.  Normally one would use geometry, but not sure with tufte-book.

Comment: @MátéWierdl, caption is already in margin note. Where you like to have? Please read documentation for `toofte-book` package. There are some example. By searching here for `tufte-book caption` you will find some more option for caption positioning.

Comment: @Zarko, I'd prefer to have the caption to be placed to the right of the table, or at least appear automatically somewhere *outside* the table.  But the workaround given here will do.

Comment: @MátéWierdl, sorry, I don't understand your comment. Regarding tables (or figures, problem is similar), I would make effort that tables/figures will have maximal  width of text and caption would be in margin, or tables/figures width would be equal to text width + margin width. and caption would be above or below table/figure. Such options are clear described in package documentation.

Comment: When the table is not wide, the caption starts at the margin and at the same level as the top of the table.  As soon as the table goes wide and reaches into the margin, the caption stays at the same place, hence the table and and caption get written on top of each other as you see in my post.  Not such a great default behavior.  I would think that in such a case the caption moves either further to the right or above or below the table automatically.  For example this is what happens to the tag of an equation when it gets wide: the tag moves below the equation.

Comment: @MátéWierdl, your comments become very opinion based and not LaTeX related. In this I cant help you. Sorry.